# I cannot open Spyder 5.1.5 with an error link image0 hasn't been detected

Tags: anaconda, spyder

I tried everything under the sun to resolve this problem from updating conda etc.. but still, get the following error:
`link image0 hasn't been detected!`
`Traceback (most recent call last):` File "C:\Users\mmawa\anaconda3\Scripts\spyder-script.py", line 10, in 
sys.exit(main())`

`File "C:\Users\mmawa\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\spyder\app\start.py", line 236, in main mainwindow.main(options, args) File "C:\Users\mmawa\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\spyder\app\mainwindow.py", line 2025, in main mainwindow = create_window(MainWindow, app, splash, options, args) File "C:\Users\mmawa\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\spyder\app\utils.py", line 289, in create_window main.setup()`

`File "C:\Users\mmawa\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\spyder\app\mainwindow.py", line 820, in setup internal_plugins = find_internal_plugins()`

`File "C:\Users\mmawa\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\spyder\app\find_plugins.py", line 92, in find_internal_plugins mod = importlib.import_module(entry_point.module_name)`

`File "C:\Users\mmawa\anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)`
`File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import`
`File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load`
`File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked`
`File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked`
`File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 843, in exec_module`
`File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed`
`File "C:\Users\mmawa\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\spyder\plugins\appearance\plugin.py", line 18, in <module> from spyder.plugins.appearance.confpage import AppearanceConfigPage`
`File "C:\Users\mmawa\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\spyder\plugins\appearance\confpage.py", line 21, in <module> from spyder.widgets.simplecodeeditor import SimpleCodeEditor`
`File "C:\Users\mmawa\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\spyder\widgets\simplecodeeditor.py", line 23, in <module> from spyder.widgets.mixins import BaseEditMixin`
`File "C:\Users\mmawa\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\spyder\widgets\mixins.py", line 35, in <module> from spyder.utils import encoding, sourcecode`
`File "C:\Users\mmawa\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\spyder\utils\sourcecode.py", line 17, in <module> from pylsp._utils import get_eol_chars as _get_eol_chars ImportError: cannot import name 'get_eol_chars' from 'pylsp._utils' (C:\Users\mmawa\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pylsp\_utils.py)`

I looked into the answers given so far online and non worked. If someone figured this out, I appreciate the help here, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) You have two Python installations: one located at `C:\Users\mmawa\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38` and the other at `"C:\Users\mmawa\anaconda3`.

You need to remove one of them (I'd suggest the first one) for Spyder to work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I received this error when installing spyder through the command line (conda install spyder).

I then uninstalled spyder from the environment (conda uninstall spyder), opened Anaconda Navigator, selected the same environment and installed Spyder through the Navigator GUI. It works fine now.